# Dynamically changing wrapper tag in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to change my wrapper tag around content. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
{!filter && <Styled.DropdownMenu>
    {Options}
</Styled.DropdownMenu>}
{filter && <Dropdown.Menu as={CustomMenu}>
   {Options}
</Dropdown.Menu>}
```

Which works. But since the content `Options` is always going to be same. I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically change just the wrapper tag in same line without repeating the code for `{Options}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
const TAG = !filter ? Styled.DropdownMenu : Dropdown.Menu;

const customMenuData = !filter ? {} : {CustomMenu};

<TAG as={customMenuData}>{Options}</TAG>
```

Comment: How to pass `as={CustomMenu}` for Dropdown.Menu then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following instead of multiple !filter checks.

```
filter ? <Styled.DropdownMenu>{Options}</Styled.DropdownMenu> 
: (<Dropdown.Menu as={CustomMenu}>
       {Options}
    </Dropdown.Menu>)
```

Or you can create separate components and use as follows

```
filter ? <StyledDropDownComponent options={Options} /> : <DropDownComponent options={Options} />
```

Which makes your code cleaner.